# Ndk samsung galaxy s

Tags: android, android-ndk

I m looking for info about ndk so to read network data (neightbor cell, ec/io, bcch) for galaxy s . Any1 know some hidden api to write something ?
I know api exist, because there is some professional app used in tlc to use galaxy in netfield process (see qualipoc app for android)

thanks

Comment: And what have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need hidden API to access telephony information. And NDK is not going to help you in this. See for example http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/NeighboringCellInfo.html